# vBCrLf is not working in my vb6

Tags: vb6

I'm recently make a simple chat room

I want my chat's output like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGqBz.png)

I'm using vBCrLf or Chr(13)&Chr(10) or vbNewLine is not like that but like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21e7u.png)

this is my code

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
'sending text1 client to server
Me.Winsock1.SendData Me.Text1.Text
DoEvents
'filling text2 with text1
Me.Text2.Text = Me.Text2.Text & vbCrLf & Label1.Caption & Me.Text1.Text
Me.Text1.Text = ""
```

am I wrong?

Comment: seems fine, what's your question?

Comment: if you want there to be more then one line you are correct to use & vbcrlf, vbcrlf is used when coding it, like your code and for example text1.text = text1.text & vbcrlf, if while you are running the program and you want a new line you can set multiline as true and press enter from the textbox, I would assume in your case it won't work just to do enter since you probably locked the text box with the output.

Answer (score 3):

set the Multiline property of Text2 to true